# Page display continues past end of HTML even though body height exceeds vh - white space below footer

Tags: html, css

For some reason, [on this page](https://www.dexilip.cz/vyvoj/herp/kde-koupim), I get white space below the end of footer on a full HD screen:

[image]

It has something to do with the content length, since the problem dissapears after inserting more content, but I can't figure out what exactly is causing it.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Share your code please. We can not tell anything by just looking at the picture.

Comment: @BoraSumer there is a link to the website

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this part (if you delete it you can see the issue is gone):

```
<div style="left: -900px;top: 1080px;transform: rotate(-305deg)" class="akvarel akvarel-header akvarel-right"></div>
```

> I removed the `left: -900px;` CSS property just to pin it on a
>   screenshot (see below)
>
> [image: Absolute positionned causing an unwanted white space]

---

### The reason:

It's placed with `.akvarel {position: absolute; etc... }` so it's taken it out of the document flow.

1080px (from the `top: 1080px;`) + the height of this element > height of your html document

That's why when you add content the problem disappears.